# Set gnuplot title depending on data read from file

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script that reads data from a file that is being appended to every 10 seconds. The data consists of two integers separated by spaces; the script simply interprets them as x and y coordinates, and plots them. I have this within an infinite loop as follows:

```
while (1) {

plot "myfile" using...
pause 15
}
```

What I would like is to be able to set a new timestamp in the title every time that the x coordinate read anew at the top of the file - in pseudo-code, something like the following:

```
while (1) {
  if (x == 128)
    set title "Timestamp: ".strftime("%a %b %d %T %Y UTC", time(0))

  plot "myfile" using...
  pause 15
}
```

Does gnuplot offer support for this?

While pondering this further, I tried the following:

```
while (1) {
  xc=`cat myfile | tail -1 | sed -e "s/  */ /g" | cut -d\  -f1`
  if (xc > 128) {
    set title "New title"
  }

  plot "myfile" using...
  pause 15
}
```

The problem with this is that xc is assigned a value (correctly) only once - the cat myfile ... command seems to be executed only once, unfortunately: although "myfile" keeps getting data appended to it, the value assigned to xc is always the same value - whatever value that was retrieved from "myfile" the first time around.

After further digging it would seem that if instead of

```
xc=`cat myfile | tail -1 | sed -e "s/  */ /g" | cut -d\  -f1`
```

one does

```
xc=system("cat myfile | tail -1 | sed -e \"s/  */ /g\" | cut -d\\  -f1")
```

the xc variable is updated correctly every time within the loop.

Comment: Your intention is not fully clear to me. Do you want to plot the file a) every 15 seconds or b) only if the x value gets larger than 128? If you can ensure that your file is constantly updated every 10 seconds, why would you have to read out the file or the file date instead of placing a timestamp just within gnuplot?

Comment: I want to execute the loop that I described every 15 seconds. I.e. the whole file is plotted every 15 seconds. When the value of the x coordinate read at the top of the file (which is the most recent one at that moment) exceeds 128 then I want to change the title. I need to obtain that value from the file to make the decision - which can't be done entirely from within gnuplot: I need that piece of external information.

Comment: Thanks for partial clarification. Your "at the top of the file" confuses me. Usually, you append new data at the end, so I would call this "bottom" of the file. Anyway, your `tail -1` command tells, that you are looking at the end of the file. You can do it with only gnuplot, without external tools. I will post an answer.

Comment: That was sloppy of me: what I meant was 'at the top of the loop'. The data are obtained from the bottom of the file, as you point out; the action to obtain them is carried out at the top of the loop.

Comment: ok, maybe you can comment on my answer whether it is what you were looking for. I still don't understand why you don't want to change the title every time when it is plotted. Why this condition with `x>128`?

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining the most recent time a file was modified is very system-dependent and may well not be possible.   If it is sufficient to use the current time instead, the simplest way on any unix/linux-like system is

```
set title system("date")
```

The `system` function returns a string, so you could further modify it by embedding it in a longer string:

```
set title "This plot generated on " . system("date")
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description I understood the following:

- in a loop plot a file every 15 seconds
- if the last x value (i.e. at the end of the file in the 1st column) is larger than 128, put a timestamp as graph title

Assuming your x values start from <=128, this means:

- there is no initial title
- if the last x value becomes again <=128 the title will not be updated unless the last x becomes >128 again.

In the example below you can stop your endless loop by pressing "s". Check `help bind`.

**Script:**

```
### plot file regularly, updating title on condition
reset session

FILE = "SO72454727.dat"

Stop = 0
bind s "Stop=1"

while (!Stop) {
    stats FILE u (x=$1) nooutput
    if (x>128) {
        set title "Timestamp: ".strftime("%a %b %d %T %Y UTC", time(0))
    }

  plot FILE u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red"
  pause 15
}
### end of script
```

Comment: This is almost what you had. In order to get the last value from column 1, I (mis)used `stats` to extract it. Check `help stats`. So, problem solved? But I am still interested, why you don't want to update the title every time, but with the `x>128` condition?

Comment: What happens is that when that value is reached the file will be renamed and a new file with the same original name and new data will be created. Gnuplot will start plotting the new data immediately, and the new title will tell me exactly when this happened. Actually, the conditional is a bit more complicated than that (after all, the file may be gone when the test is applied)  but that's the general idea.

Comment: @JaySmith ok, if the file gets updated regularly every 10 seconds, shouldn't gnuplot check in the same or shorter interval (e.g. <=10 seconds) whether the 128 was reached?

Comment: Yes. That's what I do in my actual code - what I posted were just snippets to illustrate what I am doing, without paying close attention to the actual time intervals.